# filter data frame between two dates using R

Tags: r

i want to filter data between two dates, date 1 = 2014-09-01, date 2 2015-04-30
am trying this code but it is still give data before 2014-09-01.
please help me 
thanks

```
 W <- function() { 
z <- read.csv("RainWind.csv")
# Filter by year   
z <- z[z$Year==2014|z$Year==2015,]
z$Date <- as.Date(paste(z$Year, z$Month, z$Day), format = "%Y %m %d")
# Filter between 20140901-20150430
z[z$Date >= as.Date("2014-09-01") & z$Date <= as.Date("2015-04-30"),]
z
}
w <- W()
```

Comment: Can you show some reproducible example

Comment: With code blocks, you should indent and omit the `\``s

Comment: I tried `start <- as.Date("2014-09-01"); end <- as.Date("2015-04-30");v1 <- seq(as.Date('2014-08-05'), as.Date('2015-07-30'), by= '1 month'); v1 >= start & v1 <= end` works fine